# Android, keeping socket/wireless connection while screen off

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I've made an Android application with a socket connection to a main server.

The propose of this is to turn the screen ***on*** and ***off*** with a socket message from the server.

Everything works fine when I'm debugging the app with Eclipse, when I send a `SCREEN OFF` the screen goes off *(device is rooted)*, and when I send a `SCREEN ON`, the screen goes on.

The problem is when I remove the usb cable, by running `SCREEN OFF` the screen goes off and although the socket connection is still alive *(at least it doesn't get closed by the server)* the android app doesn't receive any more messages neither send.

I've already set wi-fi always on at:

- Wi-fi > Advanced > keep Wi-Fi on during sleep > **Always**

What can I do to keep the android running when screen is off?

Comment: You'll need a wakelock or similar.  But depending on your latency requirements, you might consider restructuring the whole scheme around something like google cloud messaging, in order to let the phone mostly sleep.

Comment: The phone is going to be connected via usb 100% of the time, I have no problem with battery consumption, I just need to ensure the connection is always on!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion (google cloud messaging), I will consider it.

Comment: Use a wakelock.  But realize that Android is not designed to keep 3rd party code running 100% of the time - you may get a fairly high uptime percentage but there are no guarantees.